# Django - Search last object created for every id and keep sum off other field

Tags: django

I'm doing a query where I want to get the list of all Games, related to an specific Team, but I want the field "date_created", to save only the last date.

So here is my query:

```
 "games": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Odille",
            "last_name": "Adamovitz",
            "date_created": "2017-08-24T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Odille",
            "last_name": "Adamovitz",
            "date_created": "2017-09-18T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        },
        {
            "donation__sponsor": 3,
            "first_name": "Odille",
            "last_name": "Adamovitz",
            "date_created": "2016-06-20T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Bail",
            "last_name": "Brownbill",
            "date_created": "2017-11-10T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Bail",
            "last_name": "Brownbill",
            "date_created": "2018-01-31T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        }
]
```

And my desire query is:

```
 "games": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Odille",
            "last_name": "Adamovitz",
            "date_created": "2017-09-18T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Bail",
            "last_name": "Brownbill",
            "date_created": "2018-01-31T00:00:00",
            "points": "10",
        }
]
```

My final objective with this is to have a query with another field that sums an attribute inside
Something like this:

```
 "games": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Odille",
            "last_name": "Adamovitz",
            "date_created": "2017-08-24T00:00:00",
            "points": "30",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Bail",
            "last_name": "Brownbill",
            "date_created": "2018-01-31T00:00:00",
            "points": "20",
        }
]
```

Here is my closest idea:

```
#I get the sum of points with the name, but missing last date_created
qs = Game.filter(id=1).values('first_name', 'last_name', 'date_created').annotate(points = Sum('points')
```

With .latest() I'm only getting the last Game, not the last game related to every id.
I thought that I need to do two querysets, and then somekind of union, but idk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Max

Game.objects.values('id').annotate(points=Sum('point'), date_created=Max('date_created'))
```

This form is equivalant to raw sql,

```
Select id,SUM(point) as points, MAX(date_created) as date_created from GameTable Group By id
```

Comment: Awesome, help me a bit with that Max().
I used it with a Case which was what I was looking for, thank you.